# When formatting x-axis labels in Ng Apex Chart(Angular), x-axis labels are duplicated

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I'm using Ng Apex Charts. 
In **X Axis label** the showDuplicates property is set to false because I dont want duplicated x-axis labels.

 
 My data values in x-axis are 0.4, 0.7, 1.2, 1.3, 2, 2.4

> I'm using `xaxis > labels > formatter` function to show only integer values, no matter what data value it is and this is working fine, but the problem is the labels are shown duplicated like this: 0,0,1,1,2,2.
>
> **The result I want to be is: 0, 1, 2 in x-axis labels.**

Is there any solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tickAmount to a lower number if you don't want fractions.

For eg., If you have x-values from 0 to 3, set

```
xaxis: {
  tickAmount: 3
}
```